# Visual Studio Code Won't Run on Mac 10.8.5

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just downloaded a fresh copy of VSCode-darwin.zip from https://code.visualstudio.com/, upzipped, dragged to my Applications directory, and tried to run it. After the initial "Verifying Visual Studio App" window ran, the dock icon bounced a few times then vanished and the app didn't load. Subsequent attempts yielded the same result. Anyone else experience this? Any known conflicts or dependencies for 10.8.5?

Comment: What version of OS X are you running? I'm on El Capitan. I followed your same steps and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code does not support Mac OS X 10.8 and below. We have a dependency to Electron and updated recently which caused this.